# Observe a NSManagedObject in Swift 4 can cause crashes when modified in another thread?

Tags: swift, observable, nsmanagedobject

What I have:

a NSManagedObject that sets a dynamic property to true when it's deleted from CoreData

```
override func prepareForDeletion() {
    super.prepareForDeletion()
    hasBeenDeleted = true
}
```

And within a view, I observe this NSManagedObject with the new Observe pattern of Swift 4

```
// I added this to observe the OBSERVED deletion to avoid a crash similar to:
// "User was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it."
private var userDeletionObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
  private func observeUserDeletion() {
    userDeletionObserver = user?.observe(\.hasBeenDeleted, changeHandler: { [weak self] (currentUser, _) in
      if currentUser.hasBeenDeleted {
        self?.removeUserObservers()
      }
    })
  }

  private func removeUserObservers() {
    userDeletionObserver = nil
    userObserver = nil
  }

  private var userObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
  private var user: CurrentUser? {
    willSet {
      // I remove all observers in willSet to also cover the case where we try to set user=nil, I think it's safer this way.
      removeUserObservers()
    }
    didSet {
      guard let user = user else { return }
      // I start observing the NSManagedObject for Deletion
      observeUserDeletion()
      // I finally start observing the object property
      userObserver = user.observe(\.settings, changeHandler: { [weak self] (currentUser, _) in
        guard !currentUser.hasBeenDeleted else { return }
        self?.updateUI()
      })
    }
  }
```

So now, here come one observation and the question:

**Observation**: Even if I don't do the observeUserDeletion thing, the app seems to work and seems to be stable so maybe it's not necessary but as I had another crash related to the observe() pattern I try to be over careful.

**Question details**: Do I really need to care about the OBSERVED object becoming nil at any time while being observed or is the new Swift 4 observe pattern automatically removes the observers when the OBSERVED object is 'nilled'?

Comment: Test it by making one nil and see what happens

Comment: What is the question: "Observe a NSManagedObject in Swift 4 can cause crashes when modified in another thread?" or "Do I really need to care about the OBSERVED object becoming nil?"?

Comment: I will make more tests

Comment: When I test with @obc classes that are not managed object, I can simply set the observed to nil and nothing will crash. It seems it's a problem with keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue